Absolute location on touchpad on surface devices
The Surface Diagnostic Toolkit has a test for the touchpad that uses the absolute location of your finger on the touchpad.
Is there any way to get this absolute location?
In case that it's device specific, I'm using a Surface Laptop Studio
Screenshot of Surface Diagnostic Toolkit Touchpad coverage test
